# Design a database for an imageserver

Tags: database, image, database-design

I am working on designing a database for an image server.This server uses images of different sizes and formats.Each image has a category and few have subcategories too. I am not sure how should I design a database to fulfil the need of server.

Excuse me for the poor language.

Answer (score 0):

If I was you, I would start here http://www.databaseanswers.org/data_models/

There are many already made models. Not sure if the one for images exist, but find any of "file directory" or "image gallery" plans and implement file versions and that should cover you.